# trying to restart app on destroy and keep it running

Tags: android

typed code to keep app running in background and restart when power on and when app crashes but app don't keep running and it closes after a moment and don't restart when try to clear all in task manager this app also closed it is hidden from task manager

this code is in BackgroundServices that's called on destory

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stoptimertask();

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("restartservice");
        broadcastIntent.setClass(this, RestartService.class);
        this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
```

this one is to restart service

```
public class RestartService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {

            Log.i("Broadcast Listened", "Service tried to stop");
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Service restarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, BackgroundServices.class));
            } else {
                context.startService(new Intent(context, BackgroundServices.class));
            }


           // context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), NotificationService.class));
        }


        Log.i("Broadcast Listened", "Service tried to stop");
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Service restarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, BackgroundServices.class));
        } else {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, BackgroundServices.class));
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't register your `BroadCastReceiver` in manifest it won't work:

```
<receiver android:name=".background.RestartService"
                  android:enabled="true"
                  android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Also, I wouldn't put my code after `super.onDestroy();` . Try calling that after your service `Intent` calling:

```
    stoptimertask();
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction("restartservice");
    broadcastIntent.setClass(this, RestartService.class);
    this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    super.onDestroy();
```

Comment: don't use it then

Comment: i tried this way too but it also not working it  app closes after a time